# Why are only two links opening in the iframe and the rest in new tabs?

Tags: iframe, hyperlink

Only two links open in the iframe the rest opens in new tabs:
https://www.sjn.com/sandbox/frameset.htm

If only Link9-11 are clicked they open in the iframe. So I wonder why. Is it because of cookies, scripts, ...? I tried Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Edge. Checked for X-Frame header, '_blank', ...

All links should open in the iframe. But it only works for two.

Comment: I just added sandbox="allow-same-origin" to the iframe tag and it seems to work.

Comment: It looks like due to security policies (Cross-Site-Origin and Scripting) it is no longer supported to open multiple links in an IFrame. (developer.mozilla.org)